# How to store many images in db

Tags: php, mysql

I  Would like to know if I am storing  images for each user should I have to  make for  each image a field in the database ? let’s assume  each user will be allowed to upload 10 pictures does it mean that I have to make fields like imagname 1 , imagname 2 and so on in the database ?

Comment: Read up a bit on database normalization... ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certainly not. This is not how relational database are meant to be used. Instead use two tables: one for the users, one for the images. Inside the images table use a column to store a users id inside the users table. That way you can store as many images as you want per user and you can query all images by using a join query.

So something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id int(11) auto_increment NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE images (
  img_id int(11) auto_increment NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  image blob
);
```

Now you can get a list of a users images using something like this: `SELECT img_id FROM images LEFT JOIN users ON (images.user_id=users.user_id) WHERE users.name='some one';`

Comment: in this instance would the user_id nested in the images table be classified as the foreign key

Answer (score 3):

In a relational database system like MySQL, you would have two tables: `users` and `users_images`. For each image a user uploads, `INSERT` a record into the `users_images` table with the image’s filename and the user’s ID as a foreign key.

If there needs to be a limit where a user can only upload 10 images and no more, then this logic belongs in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Even better you add an index to the table columns that you gonna query for (it speeds your performance for a huge data table). You need to insert images with a unique id and tagged it to users.

Best that you have a images, users and user-images tables if you plan to add more than one image per user.

For a [demo of normalized table schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b528).

Comment: I disagree with the three tables thing, I'd just have the user_id in with the images

Comment: Well @Coulton it's up to you or user to design the way you need. I prefer to keep fully normalized tables and relationships. In OP's case two table schema is still bether than just bloating one table...

Answer (score 1):

```
Table User
------------------------------
User Id  |  User Name |  Image 
------------------------------
    1    | Example    | image id (for default image)
------------------------------

Table Images (With User Id as FK)
-----------------------------------------
Image Id  |  User Id (FK) |  Image name 
-----------------------------------------
    1     |   1           |  imagename
-----------------------------------------
```

In Table User, you can save 1 image as default profile image and other you can save in images table.

Comment: Why are you storing the image name within the User table?

Comment: Well you wouldn't store the image id in there, because user_id is the foreign key.  However you would be right with the default image ID i reckon :)

Answer (score 0):

No. Add unique id of user so that images will be associated with this id and later when you do the query just select images that have user id = something

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how normalization works. In your case User has a 1-* relationship with Image. So you can design two tables
1. User
2.Image table with userID refering to userID in User table

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no . You have to have two tables where you have to use  foreign keys thing . if you are using mysql  remember to change both tables to InnoDB engine . one table should reference another one with an id and all the data type of those ids have to be the same from the first table and the second table . Take a look at the example @arkascha gave , it’s a very good example it should help you .